# Errors after adding typescript to react native app

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm very new to TypeSccript. I'm trying to convert my React Native to use TypeScript. I followed the instructions here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript

After running `yarn tsc` I get errors like:

```
node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/typescript/src/types.d.ts:99:67 - error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<AnimatedProps<TextProps & RefAttributes<Text>>>'.

99     headerTitleStyle?: React.ComponentProps<typeof Animated.Text>['style'];
```

Is this an error in the node module or in my own code? Any tips on what I need to do?

I have a minimal project here:
https://github.com/jauggy/React-Native-TypeScript-Test

Comment: can you provide more information - what does your file look like, what version of react-navigation are you on etc? Even better can you create a minimal reproduction on a github repo?

Comment: I've added a minimal project here: https://github.com/jauggy/React-Native-TypeScript-Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by bad declaration typings in the `@react-navigation` version you're on. You can get around this by updating your `tsconfig` to tell typescript to skip type checking of all declaration files (`*.d.ts` files):

```js
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  // ...
  "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html